# Issue writing to file

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, tkinter

I am having problems with writing to my HTML file.

I want to be able to make my code place what I have written in HTML, but my code will only do it when I do not have any While/If statements in this definition. If I do have Whiles/Ifs, my HTML file will simply just become blank. I have no idea why this happens, and I can't seem to find a workaround.

Is there any way to use Whiles/Ifs without making my code delete everything in my file, and instead make it write what I want to in there?

```
def invoice_creator_window():
    global total_cost, total_cost_list, list_of_items, invoice_created

    invoice_created = Toplevel()
    invoice_created.focus_set()
    invoice_created.resizable(width = True, height = False)
    invoice_created.title("Invoice Created")
    invoice_created.geometry("300x300")
    invoice_created.geometry("+400+400")
    invoice_created.configure(bg = "limegreen")
    currentDisplay = 10

    print(total_cost, total_cost_list, list_of_items)

    done = Label(invoice_created, text = "Items have been purchased. Invoice has been created. Please check this program's file location.")
    invoice_created = Button(invoice_created, text = "Done", bg = "white", command = close_window)

    # 
    done.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 7.5, pady = space_between)
    invoice_created.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 7.5, pady = space_between)

    # This section is for the invoice creation with HTML.        
    html_formatting_start = """<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Games R Us - Invoice</title>
    </head>
    <body>


    <style>
    body {background-color: #F7D358;}
    h1   {color: #775A03;}
    p    {color: ; border: 1px solid #775A03; padding: 15px; width: 650px}
    </style>

    <center>
    <h1>Games R Us - Invoice Document</h1>    
    """
    counter = 0
    while len(list_of_items) > 0:
        global html_formatting_mid
        print(counter)
        html_formatting_mid = ("""
        <h3>
        <p>
        <img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steam/apps/211420/header.jpg?t=1483694369"</img>
        <br>""" + str(list_of_items[counter]) + """<br>
        <i>$""" + str(total_cost_list[counter]) + """ AUD</i>   

        </p>
        </h3>
        """)

        if counter >= len(list_of_items) - 1:
            return
        else:
            counter += 1
    html_formatting_end = """
    <h2>In Total: $""" + str(total_cost) +""" AUD</h2>
    <br>

    <b>Information Grabbed from These Links: </b>
    <a href="https://store.steampowered.com/explore/new/">Steam's New Releases</a> [LIVE] - 
    <a href="https://store.steampowered.com/search/?filter=topsellers">Steam's Top Sellers</a> [LIVE] - 
    <a href="https://www.umart.com.au/Headphones_147C.html">Umart's Headphones</a> [PRE-DOWNLOADED] - 
    <a href="https://www.umart.com.au/Microphones_496C.html">Umart's Microphones</a> [PRE-DOWNLOADED]

    </center>
    </body>
    </html>"""

    invoice_creation = open(invoice_file, "w")

    invoice_creation.write(html_formatting_start)
    invoice_creation.write(html_formatting_mid)
    invoice_creation.write(html_formatting_end)

    invoice_creation.close()

#############################################################################

button_buy = Button(welcome_window, text = "Buy", fg = "white", bg = "goldenrod", font = gui_font_10,
                    command = invoice_creator_window)
```

Note: "total_cost_list" and "list_of_items" are all lists. "total_cost" is a value. Do not worry too much about the context of these, but I wanted to clarify in case they might be affecting anything.

Comment: I'm not a Python expert, but I don't think you should be using `return` to exit from your `while` loop - shouldn't that be `break`? I believe that `return` will exit your function entirely.

Comment: (I think you could take advantage of Jinja Templates : http://jinja.pocoo.org/ instead of handling long html strings in your variables)

Comment: I'd suggest you to write a minimal (not) working example that people could eventually run, to see where the problem actually is.

Comment: When you say come out blank, is this in the browser or the html source?

Comment: This is very hard to read and therefore to debug. Try reafactoring it for readbility, chances are the bugs will become easy to spot.

Comment: The thing is, even without using return and just making an If statement, it still wouldn't work. 

Also, the html code would just go blank. That is the issue (although before, for some reason, instead of doing that, it would just not update the file at all, leaving it on "last edited" how many minutes ago it last updated, instead of updating at that moment that the program was supposed to update it)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fixed version of your code in as simple a container as possible.

```
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser
root = Tk ()

space_between, invoice_file = 5, "Invoice.html"
total_cost, total_cost_list, list_of_items = 10, [1, 9], ["Something", "Something 2"]

def close_window (): root.destroy ()

def invoice_creator_window():
    global total_cost, total_cost_list, list_of_items, invoice_created

    invoice_created = Toplevel()
    invoice_created.focus_set()
    invoice_created.resizable(width = True, height = False)
    invoice_created.title("Invoice Created")
    invoice_created.geometry("300x300")
    invoice_created.geometry("+400+400")
    invoice_created.configure(bg = "limegreen")
    currentDisplay = 10

    print(total_cost, total_cost_list, list_of_items)

    done = Label(invoice_created, text = "Items have been purchased. Invoice has been created.")
    invoice_created = Button(invoice_created, text = "Done", bg = "white", command = close_window)

    # 
    done.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 7.5, pady = space_between)
    invoice_created.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 7.5, pady = space_between)

    # This section is for the invoice creation with HTML.        
    html_formatting_start = """<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Games R Us - Invoice</title>
    </head>
    <body>


    <style>
    body {background-color: #F7D358;}
    h1   {color: #775A03;}
    p    {color: ; border: 1px solid #775A03; padding: 15px; width: 650px}
    </style>

    <center>
    <h1>Games R Us - Invoice Document</h1>    
    """
    counter = 0
    html_formatting_mid = ""
    while len(list_of_items) > 0:
        print(counter)
        html_formatting_mid += """
        <h3>
        <p>
        <img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steam/apps/211420/header.jpg?t=1483694369"</img>
        <br>""" + str(list_of_items[counter]) + """<br>
        <i>$""" + str(total_cost_list[counter]) + """ AUD</i>   

        </p>
        </h3>
        """

        if counter >= len(list_of_items) - 1:
            break
        else:
            counter += 1
    html_formatting_end = """
    <h2>In Total: $""" + str(total_cost) +""" AUD</h2>
    <br>

    <b>Information Grabbed from These Links: </b>
    <a href="https://store.steampowered.com/explore/new/">Steam's New Releases</a> [LIVE] - 
    <a href="https://store.steampowered.com/search/?filter=topsellers">Steam's Top Sellers</a> [LIVE] - 
    <a href="https://www.umart.com.au/Headphones_147C.html">Umart's Headphones</a> [PRE-DOWNLOADED] - 
    <a href="https://www.umart.com.au/Microphones_496C.html">Umart's Microphones</a> [PRE-DOWNLOADED]

    </center>
    </body>
    </html>"""

    invoice_creation = open(invoice_file, "w")

    invoice_creation.write (html_formatting_start + html_formatting_mid + html_formatting_end)

    invoice_creation.close ()

    webbrowser.open (invoice_file)

#############################################################################

button_buy = Button(root, text = "Buy", fg = "white", bg = "goldenrod",
                    command = invoice_creator_window).pack ()
root.mainloop ()
```

Comment: I just tried it, unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. I still get the same error of it making the html file blank.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Try the updated code (just because it concatenates the HTML code before saving in one go)

Comment: I'm using Windows 10, although the issue still persists even after this one.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

```
def invoice_creator_window():
    global total_cost, total_cost_list, list_of_items, invoice_created

    invoice_created = Toplevel()
    invoice_created.focus_set()
    invoice_created.resizable(width = True, height = False)
    invoice_created.title("Invoice Created")
    invoice_created.geometry("300x300")
    invoice_created.geometry("+400+400")
    invoice_created.configure(bg = "limegreen")
    currentDisplay = 10

    print(total_cost, total_cost_list, list_of_items)

    done = Label(invoice_created, text = "Items have been purchased. Invoice has been created. Please check this program's file location.")
    invoice_created = Button(invoice_created, text = "Done", bg = "white", command = close_window)

    # 
    done.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 7.5, pady = space_between)
    invoice_created.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 7.5, pady = space_between)

    # This section is for the invoice creation with HTML.        
    html_formatting_start = """<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Games R Us - Invoice</title>
    </head>
    <body>


    <style>
    body {background-color: #F7D358;}
    h1   {color: #775A03;}
    p    {color: ; border: 1px solid #775A03; padding: 15px; width: 650px}
    </style>

    <center>
    <h1>Games R Us - Invoice Document</h1>    
    """
    counter = 0
    html_formatting_mid = ""
    for items in list_of_items:
        print(counter)
        html_formatting_mid += ("""
        <h3>
        <p>
        <img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steam/apps/211420/header.jpg?t=1483694369"</img>
        <br>""" + str(list_of_items[counter]) + """<br>
        <i>$""" + str(total_cost_list[counter]) + """ AUD</i>   

        </p>
        </h3>
        """)
        counter += 1
    html_formatting_end = """
    <h2>In Total: $""" + str(total_cost) +""" AUD</h2>
    <br>

    <b>Information Grabbed from These Links: </b>
    <a href="https://store.steampowered.com/explore/new/">Steam's New Releases</a> [LIVE] - 
    <a href="https://store.steampowered.com/search/?filter=topsellers">Steam's Top Sellers</a> [LIVE] - 
    <a href="https://www.umart.com.au/Headphones_147C.html">Umart's Headphones</a> [PRE-DOWNLOADED] - 
    <a href="https://www.umart.com.au/Microphones_496C.html">Umart's Microphones</a> [PRE-DOWNLOADED]

    </center>
    </body>
    </html>"""

    invoice_creation = open(invoice_file, "w")

    invoice_creation.write(html_formatting_start)
    invoice_creation.write(html_formatting_mid)
    invoice_creation.write(html_formatting_end)

    invoice_creation.close()

#############################################################################

button_buy = Button(welcome_window, text = "Buy", fg = "white", bg = "goldenrod", font = gui_font_10,
                    command = invoice_creator_window)
```

I went back to my older use of a for loop and tried using that. Except this time, I added html_formatting_mid += (""" to it, and then before the for loop, just added html_formatting_mid = "", like Minion Jim showed.

It works fully now.

Answer (score 0):

A short answer would be, you could just write in append mode. `open (filename, 'a')` instead of `open (filename, 'w')`. This will add on to whatever is already in the file, so you may want to truncate it first.